# pass id to page that I want to show in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, fancybox

In my web app I use fancybox to show a product-detailfiche. In the main screen the user needs to select some criteria to get his favorite coffee.

If he selects a coffee in the list the product-detailfiche should open in a fancybox. Is it possible to pass an id to the page in the fancybox? So that I can get the information about the coffee from the xml in de product-detailfiche?

Some code:

```
        function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item) {
            return '<a href="' + "detail.htm?"+item.getId() + '" class="' + "fancybox fancybox.iframe" + '" >' + '<img src="' + "http://www.oww.be/UserFiles/Image/Producten/koffiekiezer/product" + item.getCode() + ".png" + '" width="210" height="280" />' + '</a>';
        };
```

Comment: Can you post some code, that you have tried?

Comment: Assuming you are simply wanting to automatically open the Fancybox on a certain gallery/image, you can add ID's to the images, or to the parent element that contains them and then use either `$('#ID').trigger('click');` or `$('#ID > a').trigger('click');` to open Fancybox. To pass it via the URL, you can use the Hash, i.e. `$(window.location.hash).trigger('click');` or `$(window.location.hash).find('> a').trigger('click');` when going to `http://www.your-domain.com/#ID` - Something for you to think about?

Comment: I thought to use "window.location = "detail.htm?" + item.getId();" and with window.location.search but opens the page complete (not in fancybox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id using a querystring.
To do that use this..

```
"detail.htm?id=" + <your_value>;
```

get the value in `detail.htm` from `querystring["id"]`

Comment: yes, but when I try that he doesn't open the page in fancybox, but just goes to the page detail.htm.